# Get properties with type K from type where property is optional

Tags: typescript

I have a type:

```
interface IThing {
   foo?: number[]
   bar?: number[]
   baz?: number[]
}
```

I want to write a generic method to delete the values of any of the properties of type `number[]` that are empty arrays.

I have used this as my starting point:

```
type FilteredKeyOf<T, TK> = keyof Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TK ? K : never }[keyof T]>

function deleteIfEmpty(value: IThing, key: FilteredKeyOf<IThing, number[]>) {
  const v = value[key]
  if (v && v.length === 0) {
      delete v[key];
  }
}
```

If `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are not optional it behaves like I expect. How can I account for the optional values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Optional properties will be optional in the intermediate
   `{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TK ? K : never }` type. This means that when you index it you get an undefined as part of those values.
2. `T[K]` will include undefined for optional values, so they won't extend TK, only TK | undefined.

What you can do is make everything required in the mapping part, and allow for undefined when filtering:

```js
type FilteredKeyOf<T, TK> = keyof Pick<T, 
    { [K in keyof Required<T>]: T[K] extends TK | undefined ? K : never }[keyof T]>
```

Full example ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=5&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUAWoDmyDeAsAFDJnID2Ym0AanADYBcyAzmFLgNwnnICuIACYQYLQSJigIQnqXIUADmADKHXC3acQeAD4Dho6bN7kYFCgH4WIfgFsARtADaAXTl8HcKDftOobsj6EkYgMh7kXgBevo4u7iQAviQkYACeiigAYsAMkFAyANIQaQDyMAA86AA0yOiFAHzIALzIANYlFDDIAArACG1V1aZk+MjOhcig7Z3dAEoQAI78wAVCVQ2uLOgTrsgQAB6Qwqx1k8GGUmFCyJbIkzYQAG7QyInOHWldda4NKcQwQQIMDACggZAiBgQSCoGAAUTsyjSAAonox+BAWBhsDpap8WDk8tAiiVyhVsbharY4gFfgBKAimBBg9jIJ4tNnoiAfEquUzAbqo5AAMmFbIAdFCdNQWs1WgAGBlEeR8SHQlBohgYnlpBLyZLEA0kEQIBjeFDMkCs6gaNBYbj-NUw+GI9LIm245AAInMFC9dK4yAA9EHkKVlKCQIww4VjRAoc6EUj3TicLUvV4oP7AyHkABZOBpZBOAySYwxuMJiCwpNuj1p73RbPB0MLZarGQV4hO6su5P19MhGDN3NwoQ4C1wVgoVDID1tSvqmuulED71KVTqHTZxeJlcpynr6h0Rgj0NwqBQChQXe92ur1PpkBguEHYDsCDgM-IC9XqBAA)):

```js
interface IThing {
    otherVal: string;
    undef: undefined;
    optString: string | undefined;
    foo?: number[];
    bar: number[] | undefined;
    baz: number[];
}

type FilteredKeyOf<T, TK> = keyof Pick<T, 
    { [K in keyof Required<T>]: T[K] extends TK | undefined ? K : never }[keyof T]>

function deleteIfEmpty(value: IThing, key: FilteredKeyOf<IThing, number[]>) {
  const v = value[key]
  if (v && v.length === 0) {
      delete value[key];
  }
}

declare const thing: IThing;

deleteIfEmpty(thing, "foo"); // Optional OK
deleteIfEmpty(thing, "bar"); // May be undefined OK
deleteIfEmpty(thing, "baz"); // Required OK
deleteIfEmpty(thing, "undef"); // Edge case I think
deleteIfEmpty(thing, "optString"); // Error
deleteIfEmpty(thing, "otherVal"); // Error
deleteIfEmpty(thing, "nonExistent"); // Error
```

Comment: Awesome, the edge case wouldn't be applicable, so this works really well. Thanks.